# How can I prevent user to send so many post requests to php file

Tags: php, mysql, security, http-post, form-submit

I have an HTML file that has a form inside. When this form submitted, it sends a POST request to the PHP file. PHP file creates a connection with MySQL DB and updates a row inside it.

The problem is anyone can get this POST request and send it to PHP file **simultaneously**, as PHP gets these requests it will perform an update in DB and will spoil the DB.

How can I prevent user to send these requests? How can I change my code and make it more secure?

Many Thanks!

> index.html

```html
<form action="send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="product">
    <button type="submit">Submit and Send</button>
</form>
```

AND...

> send.php

```php
<?php

$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'test';

$conn = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$prod = $_POST['product'];
$date = date('d.m.Y');

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "INSERT INTO store (product, date_added) VALUES (?,?)")) {
    exit('MySQL Error');
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $prod, $date);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();    
}

 ?>
```

My DB is like:

```
id  |  product  |  date_added |
--------------------------------
1   |  wood     |  01.01.2020 |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: please show us the code

Comment: @nbk Sorry, I will add.

Comment: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html

Comment: And how exactly is a simultaneous POST request supposed to "spoil" the DB?

Comment: @gre_gor I mean for example I can write a Python script that sends random 1000 post requests to file. And it DB will be full of random junk.

Comment: And how is this different from 1000 users posting a single "junk" request?

Comment: use a timestamp and allow only insert that are now() - INTERVALL 5 MINUTE

Comment: Consider using a Captcha on the form. This will stop automated/bot clients from submitting data

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using fail2ban. Please the documentation to fail2ban

you can introduce in your code a line that adds a line in a custome log file like for example in `/var/log/mysites/somesite.log`

in a way like this :

```
 <?php 
 # ( we will use this function to determine the corect ip of the spammer)

 function getRealUserIp(){
    switch(true){
      case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
      case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
      case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
      default : return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
 }



[...]
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "INSERT INTO store (product, date_added) VALUES (?,?)")) {
    exit('MySQL Error');
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $prod, $date);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $ip = getRealUserIp();  // <<<<<<<<
    error_log("Visitor from - $ip !", 3, "/var/log/mysites/somesite.log");   // <<<<<<
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();    
}
[...]
```

in the next step you must install and configure fail2ban

```
apt install fail2ban
```

then you must add a section in your **/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf** and add this in the end

```
[your_app]
port = http,https
logpath = /var/log/mysites/somesite.log
```

then you need to insert a filter in **/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/your_app.conf**

```
# Fail2Ban filter for your_app.conf, looks for failed access attempts

[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf

[Definition]

# Regexp to fit your logfile entry ... read the fail2ban documentation
# and customize as this is just a example
failregex = ^(*.) <HOST> !$
ignoreregex =
```

then you return to console and turn on the monster ...

```
fail2ban-client stop
fail2ban-client add your_app
fail2ban-client start

fail2ban-client status your_app
```